# With one checking and one savings, virtually divide into multiple funds?

Tags: bank-account, budget, envelope-system

I have one checking account and one savings account. I get my checks direct deposited to my checking account. Though, when I get my check, I divide it up into separate "funds" (or envelopes). But in reality, all those "funds" are just clumped up in one checking account. If I want to have "funds", I need to keep a record of it myself through an excel spreadsheet.

I know some people have multiple bank accounts, but I'm hesitant to do that as I have a feeling I will lose track of where my money is going (I'd like to have it all in one place).

I know there are really popular tools like Mint that automatically do it for you, but that doesn't necessarily do EXACTLY what I want.

I want a tool (if it's an exclusive tool for a specific bank, that's ok) that will allow my to move money from my checking into other "accounts" virtually. Though, in the real world, even though it's virtually in different accounts, all in one checking account.

Comment: This may wind up being closed as a "shopping question" ... not least because "doesn't necessarily do exactly what I want" gives us nothing to work with and suggests you haven't properlh evaluated that option. Besides, no sofrware ever does _exactly_ what you want unless ypu write it yourself.

Comment: This is the envelope budget!  You should check out YNAB http://www.youneedabudget.com/

Answer (score 2):

Why not just open multiple accounts at the same bank? That would make it harder to lose track of, and you could probably still get reports summarizing the balances across them. I do this and it works well, my credit union even lets me name each account so it is easy to keep them straight.